# Remove in x amountt of seconds

Tags: time, removechild

```
function colisionbueno(){
  for(var Ene in Personajes ){

  Personaje = Personajes[Ene]
    if (Personaje.hitTestObject(Marco)){
      Personajes.splice(Ene,1)
      removeChild(Personaje)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see setTimeout: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

```
function colisionbueno(){
  for(var Ene in Personajes ){

  Personaje = Personajes[Ene]
    if (Personaje.hitTestObject(Marco)){
      Personajes.splice(Ene,1)
      setTimeout(function(){ removeChild(Personaje); }, 3000);
    }
  }
}
```